# php cURL with 'application/json' as Header

Tags: php, curl, post, request

I'm trying to do this curl request using php http-build-query but it is not working.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"crawlDepth": 1, "url": "http://testphp.vulnweb.com/artists.php?artist=1"}' http://127.0.0.1:8775/scan/
```

How is the best way to create this request?

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = array("crawlDepth" => 1, "url" => "http://testphp.vulnweb.com/artists.php?artist=1");
$data_string = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init('http://127.0.0.1:8775/scan/');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',      
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);                                         

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```